# show that if L is a regular, then drop(L) is a regular

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I am trying to prove the following problem, but honestly I don't know what "proof" is considered a good proof.

[image]

I tried to prove it by constructing an NFA that start with w1 and ends with wk, but I feel something is missing.

I also tried to prove it by showing that w1 ∈ L1, w2 ∈ L2, …, wk ∈ Lk and a ∈ La.

thus Language L can be represented by:

L = L1*La*L2*La*…*La*Lk
If L is regular then L1,L2,...,Lk and La are also regular.

Finally drop(L) can be presented as follow:
drop(L) = L1*L2*…*Lk, since L1,L2,...Lk are regular is drop(L) (because we know that it is closed under concatenation)

I feel that there are some notation that I am not using correctly, I don't know why I feel something is missing but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what $L1, \dots, Lk$ are since you did not define them. The easiest way is probably that of starting with a DFA for $L$ and constructing a NFA for $drop(L)$ (hint in the spoiler below).

> Replace all transitions labelled with "a" in the DFA for $L$ with $\epsilon$-transitions in the NFA for $drop(L)$.

Then it should be easy to show that:

- If $w \in drop(L)$ then the NFA accepts $w$: use the definition of the function $drop$ to conclude that there must be a suitable word $w' \in L$.  Start from an accepting path $\pi$ for $w'$ in the DFA for $L$ and modify $\pi$ to be an accepting path for $w$ in the NFA for $drop(L)$.
- If the NFA accepts a word $w$ then $w \in drop(L)$: look at an accepting path in the NFA for $drop(L)$ and use it construct a word $w'$ that is accepted by the DFA for $L$. Use the fact that you just proved that $w' \in L$ and the definition of the function $drop$ to conclude that $w$ must belong to $drop(L)$.

I'm purposefully being a bit vague on the details, so I don't completely give away the solution. Comment if you need more help.

Comment: Isn't a sufficient proof to show that we can construct an NFA for drop(L)? I don't really understand the definition of drop(.).

Comment: I used $drop(\cdot)$ to refer to the symbol $drop$ while stressing that it is a function. It just means "the function named 'drop'", where no particular argument is specified. As you say, the only thing that needs to be done is to construct a NFA for $drop(L)$ (and to formally show that such a NFA accepts a word $w$ iff $w \in drop(L)$). I have edited the answer to remove the notation $drop(\cdot)$.